# Set memory allocation for applications in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, memory

I have an application running under Ubuntu that tries to consume all available memory. Is there a way to specify and restrict the allocations available for a given application?

Comment: can you be more specific, what kind of application ?

Comment: @vladeli it is a binary code for quantum mechanical calculations.

Comment: If the methods discussed in that dup aren't acceptable there are these methods discussed in this Q&A as well: [How to set proper monitoring of my services in a automated way? So that if one crash it auto on the fly restarts?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75785/how-to-set-proper-monitoring-of-my-services-in-a-automated-way-so-that-if-one-c)

Comment: As well as this one: [Reset running process when certain ammount of memory is consumed](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109543/reset-running-process-when-certain-ammount-of-memory-is-consumed/109557#109557). My preferences would be to use God or Process Resource Monitor (PRM) that I described in the 2nd link.